# Merge Dataframes with Unique Values but keeping a tally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I will explain my need with a hypothetical example problem.
Say, we have four dataframes, one of each person. With columns for location and date traveled.

For example:

```
#DataFrame1
   Location     Date
0  A            d1
1  B            d2
2  B            d3
3  A            d4

#DataFrame2
   Location     Date
0  B            d1
1  C            d2
2  D            d3
3  B            d3
4  C            d4
```

Now, I need to merge all these four dataframes into one. With column1 to be unique list of all locations from the four dataframes, and individual columns for each person with Yes or No against the location as per their travel.

```
#Output Dataframe
    Location    Person1    Person2
0   A           Yes        No
1   B           Yes        Yes
2   C           No         Yes
3   D           No         Yes
```

How can I approach this?

I thought in this way so far.

- I can get an array of unique values under individual dataframe (so places traveled by each person) as: `p1_places = df1['Location'].unique()`
- I can get a combined list of all the places traveled by all the people (so A,B,C,D here) by creating a set. `for place in p1_places: set_locations.add(place)`

But I do not get how to match this set with person1 and person2 and then create a column with result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Building on your intuition, the following code snippet would do the trick.

After identifying unique locations visited by Person 1 and 2, combine the lists and retain the unique elements only:

```
p1_places = list(df1['Location'].unique())
p2_places = list(df2['Location'].unique())
all_places = list(set(p1_places + p2_places))
```

Identify the places visited by person1 and person2:

```
p1_visited = []
p2_visited = []

for i in all_places:
    if i in p1_places: 
        p1_visited.append('Yes')
    else:
        p1_visited.append('No')
    if i in p2_places: 
        p2_visited.append('Yes')
    else:
        p2_visited.append('No')
```

Create a new dataframe:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

new_df['Location'] = all_places
new_df['Person 1'] = p1_visited
new_df['Person 2'] = p2_visited
```

The output for `new_df.head()` would be:

```
    Location    Person 1    Person 2
0      B          Yes         Yes
1      C          No          Yes
2      D          No          Yes
3      A          Yes         No
```

Comment: That;s neat. I was stuck on how to combine two sets or two dataframe columns or two arrays, but as couldn't without a '+' operative. Just create a list, that's a nice solution. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know that helped! It would be great if you could accept the answer and let others know how you solved your problem.